# Question about normal subgroups and quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Note: This is NOT homework. This is only self study.

> Let $G$ be a group, with a normal subgroup $N$ and an arbitrary subgroup $S$.
>
> (1) Show that $SN$ is a subgroup of $G$
>
> (2) Show that $S \cap N$ is normal in $S$
>
> (3) Show that $SN/N$ and $S / (S \cap N)$ are isomorphic groups. (edit: DO NOT USE THE SECOND ISOMORPHISM THEOREM)

Here are my solutions. I'm stuck at part 3, and would appreciate any help/hints.

(1) Since $e \in S$ and $e \in N$, $ee = e \in SN$ (we have shown that the identity element belongs to $SN$). Now, let $s_1n_1 \in SN$ and $s_2n_2 \in SN$. Then, $s_1n_1s_2n_2 = s_1s_2s_2^{-1}n_1s_2n_2$. Since $N$ is a normal subgroup, we have $s_2^{-1}n_1s_2 \in N$. Call this $n_3$. Then, we have $s_1n_1s_2n_2 = s_1s_2n_3n_2 = s'n' \in SN$ (we have just verified closure). Now, let $sn \in SN$. Then, $(sn)^{-1} = n^{-1}s^{-1} = s^{-1}sn^{-1}s^{-1} = s^{-1}n'$ (by the property that $N$ is a normal subgroup). So, $(sn)^{-1} \in SN$ (we have just verified the fact that inverses exist). Therefore, $SN$ is a subgroup of $G$.

(2) Let $a \in S \cap N$, $s \in S$. Then, $sas^{-1} \in N$, since $N$ is normal in $G$, and $sas^{-1} \in S$ by closure. So, $sas^{-1} \in N \cap S$. So, $S \cap N$ is normal in $S$.

(3) I don't know how to proceed with this one. Can someone please help?

Comment: For the third one you could look at a map $\varphi : S \to SN/N$ given by $\varphi(s)=\overline{s}$ and show it's surjective and has kernel $S \cap N$. Then you can use the first isomorphism theorem.